# setText will crush the app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, settext

Hi I am starting my first android app and trying to get the TextView changed the words after some time.

```
public class Game1Activity extends Activity {

    GameViews ngv;
    private static String gameId = "game1Activity-game";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game1_layout);
        ngv = (GameViews)findViewById(R.id.Game1);
        ngv.setTextView((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text));
    };

}
public class GameViews extends View
{
    private TextView gameText;
    private long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public GameViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initGameViews();
    }

    public GameViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initGameViews();
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView tv)
    {
        gameText = tv;
    }

    public void initGameViews()
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();
        changeGameText();
    }

    public void changeGameText()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time1 > 100)
            {
                gameText.setText(R.string.hi2);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the layout XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <game1.code.GameViews
    android:id="@+id/Game1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tileSize="24" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:text="@string/hi1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ff8888ff"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and the strings.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hi1">hi1</string>
    <string name="hi2">hi2</string>
</resources>
```

When I try to run, the logCat tells me that：

```
03-08 03:19:28.067: E/AndroidRuntime(602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 03:19:28.067: E/AndroidRuntime(602): game1.code.GameViews.changeGameText(GameViews.java:67)
03-08 03:19:28.067: E/AndroidRuntime(602):
game1.code.GameViews.initGameViews(GameViews.java:52)
```

It seems that the setText is causing the issue, as when I commented out this line there is no problem occurring.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the string value to some value in R.java not the value referenced by that R.java variable

Change

```
gameText.setText(R.string.hi2);
```

to

```
gameText.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.hi2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `null` check in the `changeGameText()` method.

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time1 > 100 && gameText != null)
{
    gameText.setText(R.string.hi2);
    return;
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Problem is that this `changeGameText()` is called by `initGameViews()` and this method is called bei the constructor `GameViews()`. At this point the class variable `gameText` is `null`.

Comment: Well, this do solve the bug, the the new thing is that it seems gameText will always be null and will never reach the part inside if statement. gameText is never initialized, I am wondering how does this work? Thanks!

Comment: The class variable `gameText` is initialized by the `onCreate()` but after the constructor `GameViews()` is called. I edited my answer otherwise you could run into an infinite loop.